# Sessioning a post request?

Tags: php, session, curl

I have written a website that connects to a server and logs in, but it won't save sessions.

session_status returns PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE, but it also says the session variables don't exist.

I then decided to var_dump the session variables and it gave me this: array(0) { }

I am using CURL with post requests.
Both machines are on the same network, and there is no reason for the deletion of the session variables.

Another note - I removed all calls to session_destroy() by commenting them out, and it still didn't show any session variables.

Is there some way of sessioning post requests, or is it purely impossible?

**Update 1** Client Connector http://pastebin.com/DeJJ8eVH
File that runs on every page to check and reinitialize session: http://pastebin.com/NuaTjmNG

The problem is the fact that the requests are going through to the server, and I try to create a session for the client (which is just a post request) and it doesn't save variables.

Comment: Question is very unclear. please support your question with appropriate example and sample code

Comment: Do I need to add a cookie for the session?

Comment: Cookie aren't safe for sessions. checkout some basic difference between cookies and session http://www.phpcubes.com/what-is-the-difference-between-session-and-cookies.html

Comment: I wasn't talking about using cookies for the same function as sessions, I was talking about re initializing the phpsession cookie.

Comment: What you can do is store your client values in your session file and than set  that as curl post parameters before executing the curl request.

Comment: What is my "session file"

Comment: Refer this for adding and retrivieng the session -: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I already know how to create sessions. That is not at all the problem. The problem is the fact that I need to use sessions through a post request from another server. I sending a post request from server A to server B and server B isn't maintaining the session after a post.

Comment: Than you need to create new sessions on Server B from the post request you received from server A.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem and here is how :

On server B, I had the sessionid echoed back to the server A. server A could then reinitialize the same session using that sessionid.